# Swift: Does AsyncStream work in a subscription-based context?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find much documentation on example usages of `AsyncSequence`, particularly with the [`AsyncStream`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncstream)  implementation, but I'm trying to understand these on a deeper level.

At the moment, I'm interested in converting something like a subscription-based [`Cancellable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/cancellable) that lives for the lifetime of a view controller and reacts to any changes in an observed property.

Is this an appropriate use case for `AsyncSequence`? From what I understand, you would observe the sequence with a for-in loop, but is it possible to continue watching for changes after the observed property has been updated once, or is it only a one-and-done type of usage?

Comment: The loop keeps going until it is terminated/cancelled/finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is this an appropriate use case for AsyncSequence" It is *exactly* the use case for AsyncSequence.

But wait, there's more! Every Combine publisher has a `values` property which *is* an AsyncSequence. If you already have a publisher, there is nothing to "convert". Just use that publisher's `values` in an async context and away you go.

Example:

```
let timerpub = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect()
Task {
    for await value in timerpub.values {
        // do something with `value`! called every second
    }
}
```